# Отделение переменных от основного .less файла

Tags: html, css, переменные, less

Собственно вопрос прост. Можно ли, например, вынести файл с глобальными переменными например в файл `vars.less` и использовать их с другими небольшими `.less`-файлами? То есть сделать что-то вроде конфиг-файла?

Answer (score 1):

*В ру-локации сайта ответа нету(или я просто не нашёл), так что создам свой.*

Можно, подключив файл c переменными через `@import` в каждой необходимой таблице:

```
@import "vars.less";
```

Comment: Дополню немного, обычно так и делается в главный (less, sass) файл подключаются через `@import`  файл с переменными, миксинами, экстендами, таблицей нормализвции и уже за ними файлы с описанием компонентов. Причем в `scss`, не знаю как в `less` расширение можно опускать, например `@import "base/variables";`

Comment: @pepel_xD, в less так тоже работает.